# How to steer 20v from ATmega pin?

Tags: transistors, atmega

I want to enable/disable 20V current with my ATmega pin. How can I connect transistor and what transistor?

Comment: How about you tell us more about your application?

Comment: One clarification: You *switch* (not "steer") voltages. Also, "20V current" does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: -

[image]

A GPIO pin from your MCU going high activates the BC547 and this draws current through the 1 kohm resistor and applies about 15V on the P channel FET's gate-source. This turns on the FET. When the GPIO pin goes low the BJT turns off and the P channel FET's gate-source voltage discharges in a few microseconds to zero thus turning it off.

Pick a P channel FET that has suitably low on resistance to cope with the load current and there should be no need for a heatsink in most cases. There are plenty of P channel FETs to choose from and I'm not picking one for you - you have to decide what package suits your circuit. If in doubt ask.

Comment: are there no solutions using one transistor? because I need to steer 8 channels with 20v

Comment: Not clean solutions - it would depend on load current and be much more critical (and restrictive) on the type of P channel FET. It can be done but the 20V range needs to be adequately described and the load conditions min and max are more critical- a BJT would be replaced by a zener diode - not much saving I'm afraid so I can't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

For just enabling and disabling you're best off with an N-FET type transistor. It is most commonly used between GND and the load. Connections go like so:

Load +: supply + rail
Load -: FET Drain
ATMega output pin: FET Gate
FET Drain: supply GND

In essence the N type FET is a voltage controlled switch, where voltage between Gate and Source controls the switch channel conductivity.

[A technical discussion](http://www.re-innovation.co.uk/web12/index.php/en/projects/open-charge-regulator/hardware/power-switching) regarding load switching including oscilloscope screenshots and all. I linked this one, because they put [a nice illustration](http://www.re-innovation.co.uk/web12/images/stories/reimages/blog/solarregulator/MOSFET_driver_schem.png) of a low side FET switch circuit. They also mention in the discussion that the 1N4001 really is too slow for catching switch off ringing and you should select a fast diode.

Comment: and will that be suitable for steering 20v from 5v ATmega?

Comment: As long as you select a FET that will turn on at 5V. Usually they are labeled as Logic Level in component catalogs. You can also use some gate driver circuits enabling you to select non-logig-level FETs that have better other parameters.

Comment: No, an N channel FET will not be suitable for steering 20V from a 5V atmega! It is suitable for "steering" 0V to a load that is connected to 20V but that is different to hard-switching the 20V.

Comment: Well yes. My solution switches the load to ground connectivity while yours switches the positive supply to load connectivity. Both work fabolously well. I've used a high side P-fet in a software controlled PSU with a driver looking very much like your 547 one: https://github.com/Ell-i/Hackathon/wiki/LED-driver-SMPS-buck-converter-components